# jstl - redirect keeping the old parameters

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I want to call my web site like:

```
http://localhost:8080/?co=grav
```

When doing this the authentication page configured in web.xml comes up and the login is done through form login. After that it will go to index.jsp where I am doing a redirect to one of my main pages of the site:

```
<c:redirect url="index-userapp.jsp" >
```

The problem is that, this redirect does no longer forward my `co` parameter, and I really need to not loose it...

Do you see a workaround?

I think it can be done like:

```
<c:redirect url="index-userapp.jsp">
        <c:param
            name="co"
            value=""></c:param>
    </c:redirect>
```

but how I put in the new value, the old parameter value from the initial request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
<c:redirect url="index-userapp.jsp">
     <c:param name="co"
            value="${param.co}"></c:param>
</c:redirect>
```